# I can't access frontend or backend after changing file/directory permissions

Tags: magento-1.9, file-permissions

I installed Magento 1.9.2.4 and completed all the instructions in the "Setting Privileges and Ownership After You Install Magento" section found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Now I can't access any part of my website...did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

what error can you see? Have you check logs?

You can open index.php at root and write `echo "index.php"; exit;` and can run website with `index.php` url.

One more thing you can do is run this script. it will set required folder/files permissions.

http://www.everyuseful.com/useful_tools/magento-cleanup.zip

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I get redirected to my main site's "Page Not Found" page.
This installation is in a subdirectory. I don't have any errors logs.

Comment: Then upload given file in your subdirectory.. Is this fresh magento?

Comment: Yes, this is a completely fresh install. I went through the installation process successfully, loaded the frontend page, logged into the backend admin panel - no problem doing all that. Then I followed the instructions given by Magento and could no longer access frontend or backend.

Comment: It seems permission issue.. Provided file resetting permission as per magento requirements.. You just need to upload that file in your subdirectory and then just access file through url in browser.  You can see the which folder/file updated which permission.. It should solve your issue.

Comment: is it in your local system or on server I can access the url?

Comment: While I do appreciate your solution with the file that I upload to fix the permissions problem, I am more interested in understanding why the recommended permissions aren't working.
Has anyone else come across this problem and is there any documentation I can read to fully understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .htaccess file

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

remove comment from above line

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

Change magento name with your sub directory name

Answer (score 0):

it might be permission issue. You can try to set these permissions

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
find . -type d -exec chmod 711 {} \; 
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./media -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find ./var -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find ./media -type d -exec chmod u+s,g+s {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod u+s,g+s {} \;
chmod 640 ./app/etc/*.xml

and check if the website will open. 
Also when you are opening any different page, you need to have index.php on the url part. 
So to include index.php on url, go to system->configuration->web->search engine optimisation. and disable 'Use Web Server Rewrites' Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm almost completely certain that it's a permission issue. My question though is why would Magento recommend permissions that make the site unusable? I have to be missing something.

Comment: Did you tried to add index.php on url when you are opening other pages?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not able to access the website.